# Responsive Design for 4 DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have some issues with designing a layout for 4 DIVs for smaller screens.

This is the original HTML/CSS

```
<div id="a" style="float:left">aaaaaa</div>
<div id="b" style=float:left;margin-left:150px;>bbbbbb</div>
<div id="c" style="float:left;margin-left:150px;">ccccccc</div>
<div id="d" style="float:right;">dddddd</div>
```

This is the URL : http://store.touchmedia.ca/mytest/scroller03.php

When the screen width is big like that of a desktop, it will display the 4 divs horizontally. But when the screen size comes to similar to an iPad, I want this to display in 2 rows. First 2 DIVs should come in the first row and the next 2 DIVs should come in the 2nd row. And for the mobile phones, one after another vertically, How can I go about it ?

Please throw me some light on it, give me some ideas, I am pretty new to web development , really appreciate it.

Comment: Check the Mozilla Dev Network and read-up on `media-queries`. You can toggle all your logic based on certain `min` and `max` `width` for example. But also a lot of other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you even need media queries for this! You just have the fixed width for these with `display: inline-block` and aligning centre.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="a" class="resp">aaaaaa</div>
    <div id="b" class="resp">bbbbbb</div>
    <div id="c" class="resp">ccccccc</div>
    <div id="d" class="resp">dddddd</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.wrap {text-align: center;}
.resp {display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 21%; margin-right: 1%;}
.resp.fixed {width: 100px; margin-right: 10px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/BrZFk/

Comment: I really like this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for CSS media queries

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You can set different attributes to an element depending on the size

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
 .a { width:50%; }

}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
 .a { width:100%; }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote… it's a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

### You can align elements without using floats or media-queries!

Using `text-align: justify` we can get CSS to evenly distribute each element over the predefined width of its parent. I find this approach much cleaner than using floats and/or media queries.

If you're wondering what the `:after` pseudo selector is achieving, it's creating a break, which manipulates the DOM into thinking the content is overflowing, then `text-align: justify` kicks in.

***HTML***

```
<div id="group">
    <div class="group_item">aaaa</div>
    <div class="group_item">bbbb</div>
    <div class="group_item">cccc</div>
    <div class="group_item">dddd</div>
 </div>
```

***CSS***

If you're wondering what the `:after` pseudo selector is achieving, it's creating a break, which tricks manipultes the DOM into thinking `text-align: justify` is initiated.

```
#group{
    text-align: justify;
}

#group div{
    display: inline-block;
}

#group:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[See it working!](http://jsfiddle.net/XSjXM/)